# Unable to link to a running postgres database docker container and run DDL commands

Tags: postgresql, docker

I am trying to run postgres in a docker container and create an user & database by linking to the running postgress container. Once the user is created I want to provide those details as part of running a Pact brocker instance. However when I run the shell script I am getting error connecting to the postgres container and running ddl queries.
Below are script and error details.

Script

```
docker run --name pactbroker-db -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=XXXXX -e POSTGRES_USER=admin -v ~/pact/data:/var/data -d postgres


docker run -it --link pactbroker-db:postgres --rm postgres sh -c 'export PGPASSWORD=XXXXX; exec psql -h "$POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR" -p "$POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_PORT" -U admin'

CREATE USER pactbrokeruser WITH PASSWORD 'YYYYY';
CREATE DATABASE pactbroker WITH OWNER pactbrokeruser;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE pactbroker TO pactbrokeruser;

\q

docker run --name pactbroker --link pactbroker-db:postgres -e PACT_BROKER_DATABASE_USERNAME=pactbrokeruser -e PACT_BROKER_DATABASE_PASSWORD=YYYYY -e PACT_BROKER_DATABASE_HOST=postgres -e PACT_BROKER_DATABASE_NAME=pactbroker -d -p 80:80 dius/pact-broker
```

Error:

```
./install_pact_postgress.sh
fae1ae3b569a75c33ed5cb7d0faad665c038eb03d9b62c1e2df694f0ce162c5c
psql: error: could not connect to server: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "XXX.17.0.2" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
./install_pact_postgress.sh: line 6: CREATE: command not found
./install_pact_postgress.sh: line 7: CREATE: command not found
./install_pact_postgress.sh: line 8: GRANT: command not found
./install_pact_postgress.sh: line 10: q: command not found
```

I am new to docker and not sure where I am going wrong.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For database initialization use official postgres docker image feature, which run .sql scripts found in the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` folder

So create your initialization script at your host machine `~/pact/initscriptdir` and mount it to that directory starting postrgres.

```
docker run --name pactbroker-db -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=XXXXX -e POSTGRES_USER=admin -v ~/pact/initscriptdir:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d -d postgres
```

Comment: You can also build your own image by adding intialization scripts inside docker.